# Cannot share docker container data via -v

Tags: postgresql, docker

Trying to play with postgres and docker:

```
 docker run --name pg -v /Users/xxx/docker/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

stops immediately. Run the image without -v the container keeps running on. If I login via /bin/sh I can see the mountpoint with the postgres default databases:

```
root@f9e0e92dae26:/# df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
none            19049892   737424  17321744   5% /
tmpfs            1025332        0   1025332   0% /dev
shm                65536        8     65528   1% /dev/shm
none           116884912 52807056  64077856  46% /var/lib/postgres/data
/dev/sda1       19049892   737424  17321744   5% /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

But I cannot share them with the host in the manner of -v option says.
What's wrong here?

---

The log says:

```
    The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
initdb: could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_wal/archive_status": Permission denied
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

---

I've tried to pass an additional shared directory to the VM, beside /Users and /, in my case /Users/xxx/docker/data, restarting the VM but that seems not to work.
Within the VM (docker-machine ssh) I can see now /data mounted. Docker machine seems to mount the last part of the full path.
Any explanation?
So with that maybe the offical postgres images could be changed (in the dockerfile?) to change the base path, examples appreciated.

Comment: You should try to debug > `docker logs pg`

Comment: "Permission denied" is pretty straightforward, no? The usual debugging steps apply (checking ownership, permissions, &c).

Comment: It's not simple as it seems. The directory at host side belongs to my own, so wrong permissions is not the real topic. I'm working with docker toolbox for Mac, it seems that's a general problem regarding the underlying VM. 
See edited above.

Comment: I'm run into the same problem a few days ago, this and a reedit thread are the only things I found on the whole internet. Any updates on how to fix this?

Answer (score 11):

After getting the exact same error, what worked for me was pruning the volumes. I never could figure out why there wasn't enough space in the first place.

Before you run the command below for any pruning, be sure to read the details here: https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-everything

If you can bear to prune the volumes, this should do the trick to eliminate the OP's error:

```bash
docker volume prune
```

Edit:

It appears some need to prune more than the volumes. An earlier version of this of this answer accounted for that, so I'm now including it again.

To do a system prune, run:

```bash
docker system prune --volumes
```

Or if you really want to get rid of everything, run:

```bash
docker system prune --volumes --all
```

Comment: This worked for me. But I'm a bit confused. It didn't delete any volumes. But now containers are running fine

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem with Vbox VM under Windows. I tried to use shared folders between VM and my Windows Os, which cause the problem with the permissions. I solved the problem with passing directory from /home/{username}/.. for a volume

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what was the actual issue. But in my case pruning the volumes did not help. I removed all the containers, images, and volumes, also restarted docker. It worked fine. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Nicolas's answer,

In my case, just pruning volumes wasn't sufficient, I pruned everything (images, containers, volumes, and networks) and then it started working. Command: `docker system prune --volumes`

**Note** Make sure the deletion doesn't affect any of the other setup.